# How to call QtCreator generated file simple example

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-creator, pyqt5, python-3.6

I have a file generated with `QtCreator` and `qt5.8` What is the shortest and easy way to call it and access its properties/view from python code? I cant seem to find easy solution(and up-to-date) so i can understand it and remember it. I have the `ui` converted to `py` and i cannot fully understand how to call it from another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way is to use pycharm:
[image]

or u can use \Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyuic.bat -x *.ui -o *.py

and then:

```
from ur_ui_class_filename import Ui_Class_in_the_file 
class UrWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super(UrWindow, self).__init__() 
        self.ui = Ui_Class() 
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Button_in_Ui.clicked.connect(function_1)
        ...
```

Comment: I have it converted. How to create the class that calls the UI class?

Comment: from ur_ui_class_filename import Ui_Class class UrWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UrWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_Class()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)